# Self inner join to get single record

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have an SQL table data as follow
 [image]

I want to display single record for product

example

```
90792 Amlaan-Hi-Power .............. Show only 1 record when there are 2 record 
90793 Amlaan-Neutral  .............. show only 1 record when there are 2 record 
90794 Amlaan-Phosphate free .........show only 1 record when there are 2 record  
90801 Acetone .......................show only 1 record when there are 2 record 
90901 Acetanilide ...................show only 1 record when there is 1 record
```

Can I do this using Inner join

I know

```
select distinct product from product ORDER BY `product`.`product` DESC
```

will select distinct (unique) product code and that to only one field i.e. product but confused how to get other information  using SQL statement

but results in duplicate records or same table...........................

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the result of the query supposed to look like? Especially, what is supposed to be the content of the `productcode` and `name` column?

Comment: This this logic of same product and name `90902 - chlorotrimethylsilane` there are 3, how to deal with them ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your duplicate rows vary by the quantity of product in the package.

You can display just the product and name with

```
SELECT DISTINCT product, name
  FROM product
```

If you want to deal with the quantity as well, that's a little trickier. This might work: it will put all product codes on one line.

```
 SELECT product,
        GROUP_CONCAT(product_code ORDER BY product_code) product_codes,
        name
   FROM product
  GROUP BY product, name
```

Self join doesn't make a whole lot of sense for this application.

Comment: Beat me to it by 4 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Use group by option for such purposes.

```
SELECT product,GROUP_CONCAT(product_code SEPERATOR '|') AS product_code,name  FROM Table GROUP BY NAME
```

It will show only one record for duplicate names.

The multiple enteries of product code will seperated by | .

Comment: Actually, `SELECT product, name FROM Table GROUP BY product, name;`